# Creating and inserting into a DB using Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

To whoever reads this,

Basically using dynamic SQL, i am trying to create a database and then insert into it. Problem is that I cant find an alternative to 'GO' since when i run it i get an error saying the newly created DB doesn't exist. I know that it cant be used in dynamic sql as it is not recognized as T-SQL. I've also tried adding ";" but error still persists.

```
DECLARE @TargetDB sysname
DECLARE @TargetSchema  sysname
DECLARE @TargetTable sysname
DECLARE @SourceDB sysname
DECLARE @SourceSchema sysname
DECLARE @SourceTable sysname
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SourceDB = 'AYOOO'
SET @TargetDB = @SourceDB + 'SandBox'
SET @SourceTable = 'GUCCI'
SET @TargetTable = @SourceTable + 'SandBox'

SET @sql = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + @TargetDB + '; ' --create new db

SET @sql = @sql +  N' SELECT * INTO ' + @TargetDB +'.dbo.'+@TargetTable+' FROM ' + @SourceDB+'.dbo.'+@SourceTable; --these 2 lines are for copying data into new tables
PRINT @sql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Error:

```
Database 'AYOOOSandBox' does not exist.
```

I know its a stupid question but I'd like to find a good alternative to "GO" or a better practice for Dynamic SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Fix your SQL! This is a major injection issue. **NEVER** inject unsanitised values into a dynamic statement. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: @Larnu I just read it, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing your SQL to not be a huge injection issue, by properly quoting your objects, you need to separate the statements into 2 commands. Then you can `CREATE` your database in one command, and then `INSERT` in another.

```
DECLARE @TargetDB sysname,
        @TargetSchema sysname,
        @TargetTable sysname,
        @SourceDB sysname,
        @SourceSchema sysname,
        @SourceTable sysname,
        @sql nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SourceDB = 'AYOOO';
SET @TargetDB = @SourceDB + 'SandBox';
SET @SourceTable = 'GUCCI';
SET @TargetTable = @SourceTable + 'SandBox';

SET @sql = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + N';'; --create new db

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

SET @sql = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
           N'INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + N'.dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TargetTable) + @CRLF +
           N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceDB) + N'.dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@SourceTable) + N';'; --copying data into new tables
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```